# Addon SDK Page-mod + Jquery .trigger() don't work with youtube

Tags: jquery, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm developing my first Firefox Add-on with the SDK. I want the add-on to automatically click on *Like* button below all youtube videos, for now.

In *main.js* I have this:

```
var self = require("sdk/self");
var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");
var data = self.data;

// Other things

pageMod.PageMod({
    include: "*.youtube.com",
    contentScriptFile: [data.url("jquery-2.1.1.min.js"),
                        data.url("ytinject.js")]
});
```

In *ytinject.js*

```
function like() {
     $('#watch-like').trigger('click');
     console.log("Liked");
}

jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    console.log("Ready");
    like();
});
```

The problem is that it doesn't work